# Need to speed up method marked with @Transactional(propagation =Propagation.MANDATORY)

Tags: java, spring-transactions, spring-async

I have a project where the pseudo code is like this

BundleService:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public transferBundleToDestination() {
      //do some validation checks here and then create new bundle
      Bundle b = new Bundle();
      dao.save(b);
      folderService.createFoldersInBundle(b.getFolders());
}
```

FolderService

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY) //I set this because if this method throws an exception it needs to roll back the bundle created in transferBundleToDestination too
public void createFoldersInBundle(bundleWithFolderInfo) {

      foreach(folder in bundleWithFolderInfo) {
              //do some validation here, if error then throw exception to rollback bundle created in previous step
              Folder f = new Folder();
              dao.save(f);
              productService.createProductsInFolder(folder.getProducts())
      }
```

ProductService:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY) //I set this because if this method throws an exception it needs to roll back the transferBundleToDestination too
public void createProductsInFolder(folderWithProducts) {
      foreach(product in folderWithProducts) {
            //do some validation here, if error then throw exception to rollback bundle and folder created in previous steps
            Product p = new Product();
            dao.save(p);
}
```

My issue is that for each bundle sometimes there are lots of folders and inside the folders there are a lot of products.  So I would like to run the createProductsInFolder asynchronously.  However when I marked createProductsInFolder method with @Async (and set up the @EnableAsync and configurations) to return a CompletableFuture it doesn't work and complains about no transaction propogated.

```
org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'
```

How should I be speeding this up? Is it possible to use @Async here??

Thanks